# Create two instances of XML

Tags: xml

Example this my XML file:

```
<a>
   <test>
        <word>hi</word>
   </test>
</a>
```

If the question request me to do 
Create a two sample instances of object for each class.

i not really sure what is the meaning
isn't

```
<a>
   <test>
        <word>hi</word>
   </test>
</a>
<b>
   <test>
        <word>hei</word>
   </test>
</b>
```

or inside a class also need to have 2 test ?

Comment: XML doesn't have "classes" or "objects" at all. As such, with no context, this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: it's from australia. and what the question wrote. the test should be an object

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the < a > tag as the root element, and inside it create two instances of < test >

```
<a>
    <test>
        <word>hi</word>
   </test>
   <test>
        <word>hei</word>
   </test>
</a>
```

You can learn more about this on the [W3schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

Comment: Please don't link W3Schools. They aren't affiliated with the W3C or any other official body, and their content is often inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'll search for better references next time. Regardless, I stand by my answer.

Comment: The answer is accurate, inasmuch as it tells the user that each XML document can only have a single root element. However, I don't see much more "there" there -- it's really a single example which _implies_ a rule necessary for well-formedness without stating that rule explicitly, and a link to a very bad resource.

Comment: so only create two test? the word have to create 2 also? or?

Comment: You can add as many < test > elements as you want inside the root < a > element. And you can also create as many < word > element inside < test > element if the data type you are representing accepts more than one < word > element. The shorter answer is that you can use as many child elements as you want as long as that is what you NEED. It depends on your requirments

Comment: as my question stated 2 sample instances of object for each class. so i just want to make sure what this question mean? to create 2 test and each test got 2 words?

Comment: If I was asked the same question, I would create a single < a > root, two < test >, and each < test > with a single < word > inside it